# How to extract DV data from a Sony DCR-PC5E video recorder

Tags: debian, video-capture

I bought the Sony DCR-PC5E back in 2001 and it worked flawlessly until today. I wanted to extract data from the almost 100 video tapes that gathered over the years and discovered that none of my Macs has a Firewire input anymore. Also when I tried to revive older Macs I noticed that they were not powerful enough to extract unaltered data from the video recorder. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a IOCrest IEEE 1394b Firewire Controller Card and installed it on my Debian v9.1 `3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux` home computer.

I installed the following Debian packages:

```
apt-get -y install dvgrab libraw1394-11 libavc1394-0 libiec61883-0
```

I connected the camera with the computer, ran the command

```
dvgrab --format raw --noavc foo
```

and launched viewing of a tape on the camera. This started capturing data, which resulted into 999.89 MiB for every 4 minutes and 51 seconds of movie, without any loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

I just transferred all my tapes via fire wire to PC.
1) Buy MS PC with fire wire input
2) By expansion card for fire wire on desk top
Windows 7 or 10 will do the trick with Nero